# Merging K Sorted Linked Lists, Why is Complexity O(N * K * K), not O(N * K)

Tags: algorithm, merge, linked-list, time-complexity, big-o

I have the following solution, but I'm hearing from other reviewers that it is `O(N * K * K)`, not `O(N * K)` where `N` is the (max) length of the `K` lists and `K` is the number of lists. For example, given the lists `[1, 2, 3]` and `[4, 5]`, `N` is 3 and `K` is 2.

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    private void advance(final ListNode[] listNodes, final int index) {
        listNodes[index] = listNodes[index].next;
    }

    public ListNode mergeKLists(final ListNode[] listNodes) {
        ListNode sortedListHead = null;
        ListNode sortedListNode = null;

        int associatedIndex;

        do {            
            int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            associatedIndex = -1;

            for (int listIndex = 0; listIndex < listNodes.length; listIndex++) {
                final ListNode listNode = listNodes[listIndex];

                if (listNode != null && listNode.val < minValue) {                
                    minValue = listNode.val;
                    associatedIndex = listIndex;
                }
            }

            if (associatedIndex != -1) {
                if (sortedListNode == null) {
                    sortedListNode = new ListNode(minValue);
                    sortedListHead = sortedListNode;
                }
                else {
                    sortedListNode.next = new ListNode(minValue);
                    sortedListNode = sortedListNode.next;
                }

                advance(listNodes, associatedIndex);
            }
        }
        while (associatedIndex != -1);

        return sortedListHead;
    }
}
```

My reasoning is that the body of the `do-while` loop will occur `N` times (as the `do-while` loop's stop condition is fulfilled when the longest list has been iterated through), while the `do-while` loop's `for` loop's  body will occur `K` times (`listNodes.length`), yielding `O(n * k)`.

Why is the above solution `O(n * k * k)` instead?

Comment: The outer loop is executed N * K times and the inner loop is executed K times

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Why is the outer loop executed N * K times?

Comment: Your description of the condition for the outer `while` loop termination is incorrect. The actual condition is when all lists have been exhausted, which based on your definitions of N and K would be N * K iterations.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I see what you're saying now, I was only considering the longest list being exhausted rather than all of them. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your resulting list will have a maximum of *n* * *k* items.  Adding each of those items costs O(*k*) (the inner loop performs *k* iterations to examine the head of each list).  Therefore the total runtime is O(*n* * *k* * *k*).